# Annotations on an overridden method are ignored in Java 8 PropertyDescriptor

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm not quite sure how to describe this problem succinctly, so please bear with me.

I am investigating upgrading our application from Java 7 to Java 8. The application relies on the use of reflection in order to dynamically create instances of various business entities (a so-called ["Adaptive Object Model"](http://adaptiveobjectmodel.com/)). When I try building the application with the latest Java 8 (Oracle 1.8.0_25) some of the tests start to fail. Specifically, there is a test which checks to see if a getter method in a 'test entity' is annotated with a particular annotation, and the test fails because the annotation is not found. The super "entity" class has some generic fields which apply to all entity instances (name, description, displayname, etc.), and in the test class the "test entity" extends "entity" and overrides one of the getter methods (getDisplayName) and adds an additional annotation:

```
static class EntityWithCompositeDisplayName extends Entity {
    @CompositeProperty("${name} - ${description}")
    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return super.getDisplayName();
    }
}
```

@CompositeProperty is our own annotation. It has a METHOD target and RUNTIME retention.

The test calls the following code to see if the annotation is present:

```
    CompositeProperty compositeProperty = propd.getReadMethod().getAnnotation(CompositeProperty.class);
```

"compositeProperty" returns null in Java 8, but not-null in Java 7. But if I try to getAnnotation() for one of the annotations declare on the super getDisplayName() method then it is fine. Similarly, if I move the CompositeProperty annotation to the superclass then the test passes, however this is not an option in practice. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if `propd.getReadMethod().isAnnotationPresent(CompositeProperty.class)` returns true. Or, even if `Override.class` shows up. Have you tried other annotations? Have you tried using `getDeclaredAnnotation()`?

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz: no, false. Override is also false. But I made some progress: I forgot to mention that the EntityWithCompositeDisplayName class was an inner class declared within the test class. If I extract the class to a top-level class then the test passes! So it's something to do with annotations on overridden methods of inner classes....

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me, you might want to consider filing it with oracle

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. I have reported it as a bug. Guess I'll just have to use workarounds for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging in the JDK source code, here is what happens inside the JDK8 implementation of the `Introspector`:

1. Each `Introspector` first introspects its direct super class for property accessors. Doing so, for each class in the hierarchy, an instance of `Introspector` is created. The super class's introspector's `getTargetPropertyInfo` is called by the subclass instrospector some point, to extract inherited `PropertyDescriptor`s.
2. When extracting the properties of `EntityWithCompositeDisplayName`, two properties for `Object::getClass` and `Entity::getName` were already extracted.
3. When extracting the methods of `EntityWithCompositeDisplayName`, the `Introspector` calls `getPublicDeclaredMethods(Class)` where any method is resolved using `com.sun.beans.MethodFinder::findAccessibleMethod(Method)`.
4. The later method checks the declaring (!) `Class` of a method to be public which is not true for `EntityWithCompositeDisplayName`. Thus it traverses back in the class hierarchy and tries to disover a public superclass that declares a method with identical signature and then returns the method of the super class. It seems like this is done in order to avoid access checks which would be required when accessing a package-private class's method from outside its package (educated guess).

The `Method` resolution using using the `MethodFinder` was not implemented in JDK7 (or earlier). As a consequence, you did get the method that you expected.

Looks like a side-effect of optimization (and thus a bug) to me.

Comment: Thanks for the research / explanation! I have reported it to Oracle, so... Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Probably the way to go. Its not very Java to change behavior of existing classes, this makes this almost certainly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about you problem and i tried to replicate the environment:

```java
public class MyAnnotatedClass extends MyAnnotatedSuperClass{

    @MyCustomAnnotation(name="annotationName", value="annotationValue")
    @Override
    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Class<MyAnnotatedClass> myClass =  MyAnnotatedClass.class;

        MyCustomAnnotation myCustomAnnotation = myClass.getMethods()[0].getAnnotation(MyCustomAnnotation.class);

        if(myCustomAnnotation!=null)
            System.out.println("ok: "+myCustomAnnotation.name());
        else
            System.out.println("not ok");
    }
}

abstract class MyAnnotatedSuperClass {
    public String myString;
    public abstract String getMyString();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
     public String name();
     public String value();
}
```

From my quick test, I would conclude that annotations in override methods work fine, so the problem may be on other point of the program.

Comment: Your test doesn't reproduce the problem exactly. I'll write a simple example test later.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem with my own unit test: https://gist.github.com/gdubya/4d99fef5bf874046f930

Comment: @GaZ I can't reproduce your gist. I get a non-null value.

Comment: Which version of Java? I'm on Linux x64 (Ubuntu) 
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: @GaZ build 1.8.0_20-b26. Please reply with `@myusername` otherwise I won't be notified.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ah, sorry. Ok, so how do I explain my result? I get the same result when running both in the IDE and from the command line. Did you try my gist after I removed the JUnit and Spring dependencies? Which OS are you using? I got the same result in both 1.8.0_25 and 1.8.0_05 (but not 1.7.0_71), so I would guess that 1.8.0_20 is also affected...

Comment: @GaZ On Mac, Java build 1.8.0_20-b26. Your Gist prints `ok!` which I'm guessing is the correct behavior.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hmm yeah, that's correct. So maybe it's a Linux-only problem? I need to find some more environments in which to test this.